# CK editor not showing

Tags: wysiwyg

Using latest Drupal 7.
Cannot figure out why CK editor is not showing.
Granted all permissions to my administrative user, cannot edit configuration because links don't work, no dropdowns.
What am I missing?

Comment: With your browser, right mouse click and inspect element, are there any js errors in the console?

Comment: Inspected text area element, no errors.

Comment: Strange thing is I went to a working site and configuration for CK editor is working, dunno why it does not work in 7.59, already submitted issue.